# Python merge multiple dictionaries with keys and values into one

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, key-value

I have 8 dictionaries with a key, followed by a value. It looks like this (simplified):

```
dictionary1 = {1: '5', 2: '8', 3: '4'} 
dictionary2 = {1: '3', 2: '5', 3: '7'}
dictionary3 = {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3'}
```

I want to merge these into a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dictotal = {1: '5', '3', '1', 2: '8', '5', '2', 3: '4', '7', '3'}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add all 8 dictionary and its output dictionary because from above details, hard to find way of programming.

Comment: This is not a dictionary. This is some weird mixed type that you created.

Comment: Your values should be in a list, then it works. Use zip to combine values based on key.

Comment: dictotal = {1: '5', '3', '1', 2: '8', '5', '2', 3: '4', '7', '3'} this is not a dictionary. Do you want some thing like dictotal = {1: ['5', '3', '1'], 2: ['8', '5', '2'], 3: ['4', '7', '3']} ?